# Will btrfs snapshots ever share page cache?

Tags: btrfs, cache, container

It's common to run multiple container images *based on the same parent*.  In theory you should be able to share page cache between these containers automatically.

E.g. some of the code in shared libraries will be loaded into RAM unmodified.  Those memory pages could be shared between the containers to reduce resource consumption (Without running KSM to clean up the duplication).

At the moment I read this only works with aufs/overlayfs.  But btrfs has snapshots that could be great for this.  (I assume this is what the btrfs docker backend uses).  Are there any published plans or ideas to fix btrfs/linux and support page cache sharing?

Comment: Better ask it on btrfs.kernel.org mailing list. These are the people, who develop the btrfs. Not us.

Comment: edit: _published_ plans or ideas?  Deafening silence is an acceptable answer :).  I guess containers are still very new, kernel development has many difficulties, and I'm over-curious about details like that.